# MySQL update not performing action

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sql-update

I am trying to run the following query,

`UPDATE candidate_assets SET show = 1 WHERE show = 0;`

to change all the rows (show) that are set to 0 to be equal to 1, the show column is just basic INT column, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the result of select * From candidate_assets where show = 0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`SHOW`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show.html) is a keyword in MySQL.  Try escaping references to your column by surrounding them with backtick `` ` `` marks:

```
UPDATE candidate_assets SET `show` = 1 WHERE `show` = 0;
```

Answer (score 3):

Use qoutes for fields with names which are reserved in MySQL like "show":

```
UPDATE candidate_assets SET `show` = 1 WHERE `show` = 0;
```